# How can I render views programmatically that are stored in a local gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I just made a local gem called RailsOnIOS, and I'm trying to integrate it with a rails project.

I access it via it's relative path in the gem file

```
gem 'rails_on_ios', path: "../"
```

This works and all modules and classes from the lib files in the gem are now accessible in my rails project. I also have a view in my gem, which is located at app/views/uikit/navigation_bar.html.erb

From what I understand, storing a view in app/views on a gem should automatically make it accessible to any rails app that installs the gem. But that is not the case, perhaps because I am trying to load the view programmatically in one of my gems lib files like so:

```
UIStoryboard.render(file: "uikit/navigation_bar", layout: nil)
```

The UIStoryboard class subclasses ActionController::Base, so it has access to the render method. When I try to run the rails app, I get the error:

> Missing template uikit/navigation_bar with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg,
>   :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml,
>   :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip],
>   :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby,
>   :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *
>   "/Users/myname/rails_app/app/views" * "/Users/myname/rails_app" * "/"

So obviously the rails app is never searching the app/views files in my gem. If I change "uikit/navigation_bar" in the UIStoryboard.render call to a view that is in the rails app, everything works fine.

How can I get my rails app to access the views in my gems app/views folder?

Comment: Is your Gem an engine? If it is there shouldn't be any problems with how you invoked the render.

Comment: I don’t know very much about gems, this is my first one so I’m not sure if it’s an engine. I used “bundle gem rails_on_ios” from the terminal to make it and then added ‘gem ‘rails_on_ios’, path: “../“‘ to the Rails app. Other than that I’ve done virtually no configuration to the gem. So unless bundled sets it as an engine by default then no it probably isn’t.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html will put you on the right path.